# Android Cipher AES encryption memory leak

Tags: android, encryption, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Good day. I'm using CBC mode AES encryption in my app with class javax.crypto.Cipher.
With CBC before encrypt any next portion of data we should call cipher.init() method. And I have noticed that this causes constant memory grow. On some devices it is "Unknown" type of memory on other devices it is "Native heap". The thing is that memory grows while crypting large file and it does not released after finish. I have checked than if i dont call cipher.init() before encrypt any portion of data memory does not grow. All objects are destoyed after encryption. No links to unused objects, especially where cipher is used. When encrypt video size of 1,5Gb result memory size which app is using will be about 500Mb, if encrypt one more 1,5 Gb video it becomes 1 Gb and system kills app.
Encryption is made with method cipher.update(), method ciper.doFinal() leads to the same situation

Would appreciate any help

Comment: It is better if you provide with android version, device info etc. I use several encryption techniques and it does not seem to be generating memory leak.
It also be the code you have, anything you can share would help.

Comment: I use Nexus 7 with android 5.0.2.

Comment: Sorry i can't share code. But can tell that structure is for() cycle in which i call cipher.init() and cipher.update() methods for each portion of data. Tell please have you used AES with CBC on Android ? and it worked fine ?

Comment: android 5.0.2 seems to be the problem itself. check those links:  http://www.xda-developers.com/lollipop-memory-leak-fixed/ http://www.androidauthority.com/fix-lollipops-massive-memory-leak-coming-soon-ish-577101/  http://www.mobitechnews.com/android/-/asset_publisher/uNazsKHbfWdP/content/moto-g-android-5-0-2-lollipop-still-has-a-memory-leak-bug

Comment: You comment is true. I have checked on devices with android 4.0, 4,4 there is no such issue. On nexus 4 with android 5.1.1 it is also absent. It reproduses only on Samsung SG4 with android 5.0.3 and Nexus 7 with 5.0.2. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 5.0.x seems to be the problem itself. A [memory leak problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79729) has been reported. Check those links for more info:

http://www.xda-developers.com/lollipop-memory-leak-fixed/

http://www.androidauthority.com/fix-lollipops-massive-memory-leak-coming-soon-ish-577101/

http://www.mobitechnews.com/android/-/asset_publisher/uNazsKHbfWdP/content/moto-g-android-5-0-2-lollipop-still-has-a-memory-leak-bug